# Подсвечивание текста при вводе

Tags: javascript

как подсветить те слова в тексте которые я ввожу в инпут

```js
 var searchKey = $("#input").val();

 var result = $(".text").text();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<br>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat mollitia, nam voluptatibus maxime sed, illum veniam harum quos? Rerum consectetur quia quaerat quos id. Aliquam repudiandae ducimus asperiores iusto illum!</div>
```

Comment: можно обернуть их в span которому задан нужный стиль

Comment: Попробуйте использовать плагин http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Comment: именно слова, или части слов тоже?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логика такая:

1. создадим элемент, например `span`, в котором будем помещать слово для выделения, и соответствующие ему стили;
2. на текстовое поле необходимо повесить обработчик события нажатия на клавиатуру. Вам повезло и выбор событий у вас широк:

   1. [события нажатия на клавиатуру](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events) `onkeyup`, `onkeydown` и `onkeypress`;
   2. или даже [такие события](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change): `oninput` (такое будет срабатывать при любом изменении в текстовом поле), `onchange`, `onpaste` и т.д.
   3. при особых случаях их можно комбинировать;
3. в обработчике проверяем, например с помощью [регулярного выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), входит ли введенное слово в анализируемый текст;
4. если входит, то заменяем в `innerHTML` текста вхождения слов на созданный в пункте 1 элемент, внутрь которого положим символы для выделения;
5. если не входит, то убираем все предыдущие выделения, если они есть. В примере я просто заменил весь текст на исходный.

Решение подходит для небольших текстов гарантированно. В случае, когда он будет большим, надо будет аккуратней оформить алгоритм замены слов, но код годный. Регулярное выражение, хитро подмигивая ключом `i`, игнорирует регистр.

```js
var $input = $("#input");
var $text = $(".text");
// Сохраним изначальный текст
var textOriginal = $text.text();
// Элемент, который задаст стили для выделения
var $span = $('<span class="highlight">');
// Было ли уже выделение в тексте
var hasChanges = false;

$input.on('input', function(e) {
  var searchKey = $input.val();
  // Можно обернуть в try{} catch, но так быстрее. Если в регулярке только один
  // один символ '\', то RegExp выбрасывает ошибку
  var regExp = new RegExp(searchKey == '\\' ? '' : searchKey, 'gi');
  var textNew = textOriginal;

  // Если нет совпадений в тексте
  if (!regExp.test(textOriginal)) {
    if (hasChanges) {
      hasChanges = false;
      $text.text(textNew);
    }

    return true;
  }

  hasChanges = true;
  $text.html(textNew.replace(regExp, function(match) {
    $span.text(match);
    return $span[0].outerHTML;
  }));
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<br>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat mollitia, nam voluptatibus maxime sed, illum veniam harum quos? Rerum consectetur quia quaerat quos id. Aliquam repudiandae ducimus asperiores iusto illum!</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. На `<input>` лучше слушать событие `"input"` – оно сработает и при paste в поле через правый клик мыши и при всех клавишных изменениях.

Comment: И не стоит буквально использовать значение из поля ввода как regex, а то будет [вот так](http://imgur.com/UXOmzxj).

Comment: @Sergiks, спасибо.

Comment: а как сделать поиск и в верхнем и нижнем регистре, но так что б при замене регистр сохранялся?

Comment: @ДимкаРудник, посмотрите, я немного починил, теперь работает с сохранением регистра. Заметьте, что в сниппете используется здоровская возможность функции `String.prototype.replace`, уверен, что о ней мало кто знает.

Answer (score 1):

еще один вариант

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(".text").html($(".text").text().replace(
    new RegExp('(' + $('#input').val() + ')', 'gi'),
    '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'
  ));
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
  $(".text").html($(".text").text().replace(
    new RegExp('(' + $('#input').val().replace(/(\[|\^|\$|\/|\\|\+|\*)/g, '\\$1') + ')', 'gi'),
    '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'
  ));
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Highlight regex">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Highlight text">
<br>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat mollitia, nam voluptatibus maxime sed, illum veniam harum quos? Rerum consectetur quia quaerat quos id.\s+/ Aliquam repudiandae ducimus asperiores iusto illum!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без регулярных выражений, в любом регистре. И копия текста и поисковая фраза приводятся в верхнему регистру для поиска:

```js
var $input = $("#search")
  ,$text = $("#text")
  ,src = $text.text()         // исходный текст
  ,srcUp = src.toUpperCase()  // копия в заглавных
  ,$found = $('#found')       // вывод счётчика
;

function highlight(e) {
  var search = $input.val()
    ,searchUp = search.toUpperCase()
    ,cursor = 0 // где закончили искать
    ,found = 0  // сколько нашлось
    ,inc = search.length
    ,position   // начало очередного совпадения
    ,result = ''
  ;

  if( !inc) {
    $text.text(src);
    $found.text('');
    return;
  }
  while( !!~(position = srcUp.indexOf( searchUp, cursor))) {
    result += src.substring( cursor, position);
    result += '<span class="highlight">' + src.substr( position, inc) + '</span>';
    cursor = position + inc;
    found++;
  }
  result += src.substring( cursor);
  $text.html( result);
  $found.text( found ? "найдено: " + found : '');
};
$input.on('input', highlight);
```

```css
body {font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif}
.highlight{background-color:#F90}
#found{ color:#777} #text{margin-top:20px;line-height:15pt}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="что ищем?">
<span id="found"></span>
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat mollitia, nam voluptatibus maxime sed, illum veniam harum quos? Rerum consectetur quia quaerat quos id. Aliquam repudiandae ducimus asperiores iusto illum!</div>
```

P.s. добавил счётчик найденных фрагментов.

Comment: Если так низко работать со строками, может быстрее тогда будет собирать `$text` из DOM элементов? То есть не к `result` плюсовать кусок строки, а потом ставить `innerHTML`, но сразу добавлять текст через `appendChild(createTextNode('_'))`, а элемент через `appendChild(span.cloneNode().innerHTML = '_')` к `$text`. Как считаете?

Comment: Любые манипуляции с DOM скорее всего, медленнее операций со строкой – поэтому делаю ставку на свой вариант: сначала сформировать, потом разом отправить в DOM. Чтобы знать наверняка, надо делать тесты. Несколько repaint'ов точно дольше одного.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно, вот код без jquery.

```
'use strict';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
 let input = document.querySelector('#input');
 let text = document.querySelector('.text');
 // Сохраним изначальный текст
 let textOriginal = text.textContent;
 let span = document.createElement('span');
 span.classList.add('highlight');
 // Было ли уже выделение в тексте
 let hasChanges = false; 
 input.addEventListener('input', function () { 
   let searchKey = input.value;
   // Можно обернуть в try{} catch, но так быстрее. Если в регулярке только один
   // один символ '\', то RegExp выбрасывает ошибку
   let regExp = new RegExp(searchKey == '\\' ? '' : searchKey, 'gi');
   let textNew = textOriginal;
   // Если нет совпадений в тексте
   if (!regExp.test(textOriginal)) {
     if (hasChanges) {
       hasChanges = false;
         text.innerHTML = textNew;
     }
     return true;
   }
   hasChanges = true;
   function repl (match) {
     span.innerHTML = match;
     return span.outerHTML;
   }
   if(input.value.trim() === "" ) {
      text.innerHTML = textNew;
   }
   else {
      text.innerHTML = textNew.replace(regExp, repl);
   }
  });
});


<body>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat mollitia, 
      nam voluptatibus maxime sed, illum veniam harum quos? 
      Rerum consectetur quia quaerat quos id. 
      Aliquam repudiandae ducimus asperiores iusto illum!
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


style.css
.highlight {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
```